# Kernel panic - not syncing: no init found. Try passing init=option to kernel

Tags: boot, 13.04

I formatted all the partitions in  my computer to a single `ext4` partition and did a fresh installation of Ubuntu 13.04. I'm getting:

```
Failed to execute /init
Kernel panic - not syncing: no init found. Try passing init=option to kernel.
```

Even on clean reinstall the issue persist. Booting from recovery mode leads to same error, so not able to reach the terminal. But able to boot from Live CD.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling and/or checking the disk health with the disk utility?

Comment: I have reinstalled couple of times, but same issue persist. Yet able to boot ubuntu from LiveCD.

Comment: I think you should check the disk health as @psusi mentioned. Booting from live cd is not going to use the HDD.

Comment: 12.04 worked like breeze.

Comment: I suggest that you follow the suggestions from @psusi and Selva. I know that the previous version worked, but not only have you changed the partitioning, but also disks do occasionally fail at coincidental times (it has happened to me). You can also try deleting and recreating the partitions, just in case something faulty happened then. You can even format (using the Disks utility) the entire drive, which will recreate the disk partition table.

Comment: 13.04 i386 works fine for me. The issue is with 13.04 amd64. I faced the same issue in two machines, (one with 4GB and another with 8GB RAM, both running with Win7 64 bit). When installed 13.04 i386 it worked fine on both machines. You guys still feel disk health check is needed.

Comment: I get this error with 12.04.2 (64bit). Now the laptop is totally frozen, and would not turn off when holding the power button. Need to remove battery! Previously it was booting beyond something like "tsc clock ...". I do not understand what is wrong with this hardware...

Comment: Try installing 32bit OS, that should fix the issue

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the solution to this turned out to be [disabling Secure Boot in the BIOS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn481258.aspx). Before doing this, I was not able to boot from my hard drive or from a Live DVD. However, I could boot from a live USB, so my symptoms were slightly different. Various distros each behaved a little differently, but none would fully boot and no solutions others had posted worked for me. This was a Lenovo x201 laptop formerly running Windows 7.