# Kernel Panic - no working init found

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, kernel

I can't copy paste the error message so here is a picture

[image: screenshot of the error]

A couple months ago, I set up a dual boot with Ubuntu and Windows on my HP laptop for the first time. It worked fine for about one and a half months before Windows stopped working after a Windows update.

I didn't really care as I was primarily just using my laptop with Ubuntu for school and my PC at home, but yesterday I tried booting windows again and for some reason it just started working again, reinstalling windows and suddenly working again, but now when I try to boot Ubuntu it tells me "kernel panic - not syncing: No working init found". I get this for all the options in advanced options as well, even the recovery mode.

Is there a fix for this or do I need to redo the dual boot? I'm willing to add any additional information if needed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kernel panic - not syncing: no init found. Try passing init=option to kernel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/317521/kernel-panic-not-syncing-no-init-found-try-passing-init-option-to-kernel)

Comment: No, this did not fix it.